# How can this be a JSON Schema

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I'm trying to validate that a JSON Schema is actually a JSON Schema, and not an instance, as I have read, resource for that is validate against meta-schema e.g:

- Core validation meta-schema (http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema)
- Older versions meta-schema (https://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema)

I have tried with different validation libraries, [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) for Java, and [jsonschema](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/) for Python to have more assurance, but I keep on obtaining the funny assertion that this is a valid JSON Schema instance.

```
{
    "hey" : {
        "you" : {
            "how" : {
                "dyd" : "Very well, ty"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm coming here because it seems obvious I have some big misconception or misunderstanding, as I cannot understand how a clear JSON instance (it declares no data types) can be validated as a JSON Schema instance.

Initial problem I wanted to solve, as I stated on the beginning, is how to validate a JSON Schema, but if any JSON valid instance is too a valid JSON schema (as results are throwing), how to assert this?

Comment: Maybe pick a few more tags here. E.g. `json-schema` instead of `json` – that might attract quicker responses next time. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: JSON Schema is designed for extensibility. That means it allows any kind of additional properties to be added as long as they are not conflicting with the known/expected keywords.

In your case, the `hey` property is certainly not a known keyword, i.e. it is simply being ignored during validation. That leaves you with the valid JSON Schema `{}` which allows any type.

How to ensure something is actually a JSON Schema then?
That depends on how much narrower you want to define the term.

1. You could enforce that the top-level needs to define a particular `$schema` version.
2. You could enforce that at least on the top-level there is a valid `type` attribute.
3. If you know where those JSON Schemas are coming from and that they are not making use of this extensibility, you could manipulate your target Meta JSON Schema and include `”additionalProperties”: false` as top-level property before triggering the validation.