# JSON schema recursion doesn't seem to properly validate

Tags: jsonschema

I'm going through the docs to try and figure out how loops work so I can validate every object of an array of objects match the schema.

It seems like recursion is what I want but the example given doesn't work: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html

I'm trying to validate that example but it's always "valid". I tried changing all the field names in the JSON and it doesn't matter:

[image]

I'm not sure what's happening. For this example how would I validate every child matches the person schema (without statically writing out each one in the schema).

For example, I want to valid this JSON. there could be any number of objects under `toplevel` and any number of objects under "objectsList". I want to make sure every object under "objectsList" has the right field names and types (again without hard coding the entire thing in the schema):

```
{
  "toplevel": {
    "objectOne": {
      "objectsList": [
        {
          "field1": 1231,
          "field2": "sekfjlskjflsdf",
          "field3": ["ssss","eeee"],
        },
        {
          "field1": 11,
          "field2": "sef",
          "field3": ["eeee","qqqq"],
        },
        {
          "field1": 1231,
          "field2": "wwwww",
          "field3": ["sisjflkssss","esdfsdeee"],
        },
      ]
    },
    "objectTwo": {
      "objectsList": [
        {
          "field1": 99999,
          "field2": "yuyuyuyuyu",
          "field3": ["ssssuuu","eeeeeee"],
        },
        {
          "field1": 221,
          "field2": "vesdlkfjssef",
          "field3": ["ewerweeee","ddddq"],
        },
      ]
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Same issue as here: [How can this be a JSON Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60152271/5127499)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's wrong?

The problem here is not the recursion – your schema looks good.

The underlying issue is the same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61038256/5127499

> JSON Schema is designed for extensibility. That means it allows any kind of additional properties to be added as long as they are not conflicting with the known/expected keywords.

#### Solution

The solution here is to add `"additionalProperties": false` in your "person" (from the screenshot) and top-level schema to prevent those incorrect objects to be accepted. Same goes for your second example: in any definitions of `"type": "object"` you'd have to add `"additionalProperties": false` if you don't want to allow these extraneous properties to be defined.

Alternatively, you can declare your expected properties as `required` to ensure that at least those are present.

---

#### Why?

As per [json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#properties) (emphasis mine):

> The `additionalProperties` keyword is used to control the handling of extra stuff, that is, `properties` whose names are not listed in the properties keyword. **By default any additional properties are allowed.**
>
> The `additionalProperties` keyword may be either a boolean or an object. If `additionalProperties` is a boolean and set to false, no additional properties will be allowed.

Comment: its disappointing the official example from their own help docs doesnt include this. it would have made it so much clearer

Comment: @red888 for that last part in your question you’d have to include `additionalProperties` with an object/schema as its value, if you don’t care about the property names but their contents.

Answer (score 0):

To address the screenshot you posted and why the instance passes:

1. The schema is looking to find a `person` property, but that property doesn't exist.
2. The schema does not declare that `person` is required.
3. The schema does not declare requirements on undefined properties, so it will always accept the `personsdfsd` property with whatever value is in it, without checking it further.

So in short, your JSON data is bad and your schema doesn't have any protections against that.

Other than that, your schema looks good.  It should validate that items in the `children` property match the `person` definition's subschema.